# NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin unresolved?

Tags: iphone, swift

I'm developing a Swift app in Xcode 6.1 targeting iOS >= 7 and can't use NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin because it's unresolved. I've googled it but all I find are examples that use it, apparently without issue. Current docs on Apple's site show it as valid. Has anyone encountered / solved the same problem?

Edit:
I've got it working with NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin (thanks Matt) which I had tried yesterday, but it only works with the target context set to nil. Yesterday when I was passing a valid context, anything I passed in "options" showed as unresolved. Strangely, today if I pass a valid context, the compiler gives me a different error -- "NSString is not identical to NSObject" on my font attributes! I wonder if this is just some quirky bug in the Swift compiler? Anyway, here's the code that eventually compiled:

```
    var textStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.defaultParagraphStyle().mutableCopy() as NSMutableParagraphStyle
    textStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Left

    let fontAttributes = [
        NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: tileSize * CLUES_FONT_SCALE)!,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor(),
        NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: textStyle
    ]

    size = text.boundingRectWithSize(
        CGSize(width: width, height: 1000),
        options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin,
        attributes: fontAttributes,
        context: nil
    )
```

Note that if I replace:

```
NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin
```

with

```
NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
```

as shown in the Apple docs, I get "use of unresolved identifier".

Comment: What error do you get with it, exactly, and can you post a small complete reproduction? I've just typed some code into a Playground that compiles fine with it. Then I pasted it into an actual app I'm developing, and it still compiled and linked fine. But I'm sort of stumbling in the dark unless you can tell me what's actually failing for you...

Comment: I'd [report](https://bugreport.apple.com) that misleading error message as a compiler bug. There's a lot of that particular type in Swift, where one incorrect parameter value causes an error that ostensibly relates to another, perfectly good parameter. (Also, if you've solved your problem now, you should probably post it as an answer to your own question and accept it...)

Answer (score 3):

I just fired up Xcode 6.1, created a Swift iOS project with a deployment target of iOS 7.0, and pasted the following code into my application's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
let attrib_string = NSAttributedString(string: "Foo")
let rect = attrib_string.boundingRectWithSize(
    CGSize(width: 100, height: 100),
    options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin,
    context: nil)
println(rect)
```

It compiled, linked and ran fine, and printed the result to the console:

```
(0.0,0.0,20.6777,13.8)
```

You may need to edit your question to provide a complete example, and the exact error message you're getting. I couldn't see any oddities; using the fully qualified enum value of `NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin` worked fine, too.